# Is it possible to create a calendar view with two entries per item?

Tags: list-view, calendar

I need a Calendar view, that shows two calendar entries per list entry (one for the begin date and one for the end date).

Is it possible to do this by creating a custom View Type (and maybe deriving from the calendar view type), or is there some alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some info on creating custom list definitions that may help you.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-reuse-your-list-definition-in-a-SharePoint-feature.aspx

http://mo.notono.us/2009/02/moss-dreaded-schemaxml.html

And some on calendar controls.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/01/24/creating-sharepoint-global-calendar.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check out your links, but I solved my problem in another way in the meanwhile: http://blogs.myfirstsharepoint.de/archive/2010/11/24/sharepoint-2010-%E2%80%93-aufgaben-anfangs-und-f%C3%A4lligkeitsdatum-als-zwei-termine-anzeigen.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could probably build the view you want with a Data View Web Part (DVWP). DVWPs are XSL-driven and really the only contraints on what you can show on the page is your imagination and what data you have available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm searching for: I wanted to create a View for the List ...

Comment: You can link a DVWP to the list datasource, making it a "view" of your data.  This has the advantage that you do not have to deploy a solution.

Comment: Exactly. Views are simply pages with a List View Web Part (LVWP) on them. You can replace that with a DVWP and format away...

Comment: Yes, I know but a) to my knowledge Microsoft discourages using the view pages for other webparts and b) I would have to create the xsd from scratch, while SharePoint already has this kind of view build in...

Comment: You don't need an XSD. DVWPs are "list aware" and allow you to format the list items however you want. As for Microsoft discouraging this, I've never hear that, and people do this all the time.